# Full calendar showing events on month but not week/day timegrid

Tags: php, json, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-4

I'm trying to use full calendar. I am successfully rendering the events per day when using the month view. But when I switch to a week timegrid or a day timegrid, even though the events are showing the correct start time, the event is not rendered on the week or day time grid.

[image]
[image]

Here is my php code where I'm creating an array:

```
$events = array();
foreach ($todos as $event) {
            array_push($events, ['title' => $event->content, 'start' => $event->view_date.'T'.$event->appointment_time, 'backgroundColor' => $event->typeColor($event->type)]);
        }
```

and here is what the php returns when i console log `$events`:

```
Array(3)
0:
title: "Test of the voice integration system"
start: "2020-02-21T07:15:00"
backgroundColor: "#b1b3b1"
allDay: false
1:
title: "Test"
start: "2020-02-21T10:14:00"
backgroundColor: "#b1b3b1"
allDay: false
```

and here is my full calendar set up:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/4.2.0/core/main.min.js" integrity="sha256-GBryZPfVv8G3K1Lu2QwcqQXAO4Szv4xlY4B/ftvyoMI=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/4.2.0/daygrid/main.min.js" integrity="sha256-FT1eN+60LmWX0J8P25UuTjEEE0ZYvpC07nnU6oFKFuI=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/4.2.0/interaction/main.min.js" integrity="sha256-MUHmW5oHmLLsvmMWBO8gVtKYrjVwUSFau6pRXu8dtnA=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/4.2.0/timegrid/main.min.js" integrity="sha256-L9T+qE3Ms6Rsuxl+KwLST6a3R/2o6m33zB5mR2KyPjU=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script>
    var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');
    var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
      plugins: [ 'dayGrid',
                  'interaction',
                  'timeGrid'
                ],
      header: {
              left: 'prev,next today',
              center: 'title',
              right: 'dayGridMonth, timeGridWeek, timeGridDay'
              },
      events: {!!json_encode($events)!!},
      height: "auto",
      eventClick: function(info){console.log(info)}
    });
    calendar.render();
</script>
```

So I'm creating an array, then sending it to my view and assigning the events parameter as the value of that array. If the calendar is rendering it correctly on the month view, what am I doing wrong so that it's not rendering on the week or day view?

Comment: please show the actual JSON which is being generated by your code, to match the screenshots above. From just the PHP code, we cannot tell precisely what the content of the JSON will be. Then we can easily make a mockup of your calendar and run it, to try and reproduce the issue.

Comment: i've edited my question to include that info. thanks for taking the time to read :)

Comment: Thanks. Based on that data I can't reproduce your issue. Demo: https://codepen.io/ADyson82/pen/XWbNXYp . I suggest you maybe check the source of your calendar page when it's been rendered in the browser (using the browser's View Source) feature and double-check that the JSON rendered by `{!!json_encode($events)!!}` doesn't have any problems in it. Although it's hard to see what problem there could be which would result in this issue.

Comment: The only other thing I can possibly think of which could cause the events not to show in one specific view is maybe some mistake in your CSS - if you have maybe modified the fullCalendar CSS, or forgotten to include one of its CSS files in your page, or got some of your own CSS included in the page which accidentally conflicts with styles which are used to render the events, that could potentially cause a problem. But I'm only speculating. You'd perhaps be able to double-check your code and also use your browser's element inspector to see if anything like that is happening.

Comment: do you think the order of my scripts makes a difference?

Comment: The order of the scripts looks fine. Anyway you'd probably get a console error if they weren't in an ok order.

Comment: do you have any class on table that has overflow set to hidden?

Comment: if so try removing table td { 
   overflow: hidden !important; //Remove this to fix the issue.
}

Comment: No, this is my entire table element: ` <div id='calendar'></div>`. I pretty much copied everything from the getting started section on their docs page

Comment: even when i copy the working code pen from the comment above, i'm still getting the same error. i really don't understand this

Comment: inspect your web page and check whether table is having overflow:hidden , if so then remove it

Comment: @thisgirish....that was it!!!! i added "*{overflow: inherit !important;}" to my master layout and now everything shows. What a weird quirk. How on earth did you think to suggest that as a fix? Also, if you post that as an answer, i'll accept it to give you the points. Thanks so much, I would have never figured that out in a million years

Comment: @maximus1127 Great indeed, i have edited my previous answer might help someone in future, Upvote and accept as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this, might help

```
 [{'title': 'Successful','allDay': false,'start': 1266398223,'end': 1266398266,'url': '/shlk/cgi-bin/getshlkrunlog.pl?i=21'}]
```

check syntax though

or using JS

```
 $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    ...
allDayDefault: false,
    ...
});
```

or if it's a css Issue add following

```
table td
{
overflow: inherit !important;
}
```

Comment: i just plugged that in, still no luck :(

Comment: yes i've read the docs, but i haven't been able to use their examples to figure out this problem

Comment: events returned in the JSON included an "allDay" name/value pair set to false

Comment: i've added the "allDay:false" and the end time but i'm still getting the same results

Comment: can you please create JSfiddle and share it

Comment: this is part of a larger laravel project, i'm not sure how to create a fiddle of just this portion of it as there's php and js tied into the whole page

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue today and it was linked to the duration attribute not being undefined.
So if you are working with dynamic duration values for your events/sessions, check that it was fallback value.

I changed this:

```js
 duration: {
      minutes: state.service.duration // undefined,
    },
```

to this:

```js
 duration: {
      minutes: state.service.duration ?? 60,
    },
```