# full calender not displaying the events on the timeGridWeek,timeGridDay,listMonth

Tags: javascript, html, css, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-6

I'm using FullCalendar in my web application, and I'm having trouble getting events to show up on the timeGridWeek and timeGridDay views. The events show up fine on the dayGridMonth view, but when I switch to the timeGridWeek or timeGridDay view, the events disappear.

I've checked that the events have valid start and end times, and that the views are properly configured to display the timeGridWeek and timeGridDay views. I'm using FullCalendar version 6.1.4, and I've included the timeGridPlugin script in my HTML file.

```
var calendarEl = document.getElementById("calender");
var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
    theme: true,
slotMinutes: 10,
allDaySlot: false,
    headerToolbar: {
        left: "prev,next today",
        center: "title",
        right: "dayGridMonth,timeGridWeek,timeGridDay,listMonth"
    },

    height: 800,
    contentHeight: 780,
    aspectRatio: 3,  

    nowIndicator: true,
    now: new Date(),

    views: {
        dayGridMonth: { buttonText: "month" },
        timeGridWeek: { buttonText: "week" },
        timeGridDay: { buttonText: "day" }
    },
    droppable: true,
    initialView: "dayGridMonth",
    initialDate: new Date(),
    eventDisplay: 'auto',
    editable: true,
    dayMaxEvents: true, // allow "more" link when too many events
    navLinks: true,
    eventDrop: function(info) {
        // Handle the event drop
        console.log(info.event.title + " was dropped on " + info.event.start.toISOString());
      },
      locale: 'fr',
      allDayDefault: false,
      events: [ // Add some events to the calendar
        {
            id:20,
          title: 'Event 1',
          start: new Date()
        },
        {
            id:522,
          title: 'Event 2',
          "start"  : "2023-03-11 12:00",
                "end" : "2023-03-11 15:00",
                allDay: false
        }
      ], 
   



    
});

calendar.render();
```

Comment: check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60332894/full-calendar-showing-events-on-month-but-not-week-day-timegrid

Comment: @James i tried to add table td { overflow: inherit !important; } to the css but it's not working

Comment: I can't reproduce your issue based on the information you've provided  - demo: https://codepen.io/ADyson82/pen/VwGMdWQ . If you think there's a CSS issue affecting this somehow then, please a) provide us a [mre] here including CSS which is affecting things (based on your experiments), and b) you can try removing all non-fullCalendar CSS from your page, and if that resolves the issue, you can then add the CSS back in one rule at a time, until you have a problem again. That should help to show you where the issue is. Thanks.